# : Run code first time a package is installed or used

Tags: r, installation, package

I am busy writing a package for a customer with little knowledge about R. Given their complex data structure, I need to set up a "data base" within R containing tons of information obtained from a set of spreadsheets they get from another company. As they can't install SQL or so on their computers (ICT has some power control issues...), I've written an emulation in R, based on a specific directory structure. Now I want to run this automatically, but only the first time the package is loaded. Something like `.First.lib`, but then `.VeryFirst`.

Any idea on how to load a piece of code the first time a package is loaded? I couldn't really find it anywhere in the manuals, so all pointers are welcome.

Comment: Why not just have `.First.lib` or `.onLoad` check if the "data base" has been created?

Comment: @Joshua: I've been considering the same, but wondered if it actually was possible in R to detect if a package is loaded for the first time. I've been looking into the possibility of using the INSTALL file as well, but I don't really grasp completely yet how they have to be used.

Comment: I don't think you can check if the package is loaded for the very first time.  But if you check for the "data base" and it's not there, you create it (which would certainly happen on the very first load).  The next time you load the package, you check for the "data base", see that it's already there, and move on.

Comment: Can you teach the client to run a very specific function only on the first load? Tip: loadMeOnlyWhenJorisSaysSo().

Comment: Well... they have better management skills than I do. Each to his job I suppose if you catch my drift...

Answer (score 4):

It's in the manuals.

Basically you have two code paths:

1. packages without a NAMESPACE can use a function `.First.lib()`, typically from `R/zzz.R`
2. packages with a NAMESPACE can use a function `.onLoad()`, also often from `R/zzz.R`.

I have used this for tricks like having a package update itself (!!) when loaded.  That required not using a NAMESPACE and running `utils::update.packages()` before actually loading binary code.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but don't these functions load the code every time you load the package, or did I get the help files completely wrong? I'd like to call the code only the first time the package is loaded.

Comment: Sure, so you use `file.exists()` and friends to check whether the structure exists and skip creating it the second, third, ... time around.  But you asked where to create it on startup, and I tried to answer that question.

Comment: Is it possible for a package to update itself on windows?  Or does the weird file locking cause problems?

Comment: Yes, I got it working on Windows despite the awful locking by not using a NAMESPACE which delays the dynamic loading. I then call `library.dynam()` after the call to `update.packages()`. That worked -- but it is a hack (as I'd rather keep a NAMESPACE).

Comment: then we understood eachother wrong. I meant the _first_ startup. I'm well acquainted with onLoad and .First.lib

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel my package requires to ask the user some information the first time is run and store them in ~/.myrpkg. So I use if (!file.exists(~/myrpkg/info)) { ask_info() }. ask_info is a function that uses readline to let the user insert the required details. However, when the package is installed, I see that the questions are asked but the user is not prompt to insert them. And the file is filled with I don't know what.

Is there a nicer way to handle this? I really would like my package to prompt for the user input when it is installed (or the first time is loaded)

Answer (score 0):

What about specifying a path and nomenclature for them to put the spreadsheets into. You can recurse the directory for updates and files. I do this for a similar problem.

2010 08.xls
2010 09.xls

You could use a readline() to prompt for new data ranges as well making it so they only have to type the new month. And if the directory ever changes, it's not difficult to teach someone how to setwd() or to update it yourself using a script that checks something on your personal/company server.

Are they actually loading R to run the package? Or is it all command line?