# Unclear warning when defining custom pipe operator

Tags: r, tidyverse

In my process I need to perform many `dplyr::inner_join`s. Thought I might define a custom pipe operator for it as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475923/custom-pipe-to-silence-warnings):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

df1 <- tibble(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
df2 <- tibble(a = 1:10, c = 21:30)

`%J>%` <- function(lhs, rhs){
  inner_join(lhs, rhs)
}

df1 %J>% df2
```

This works as expected and I get:

> ```
> Joining, by = "a"
> # A tibble: 10 x 3
>        a     b     c
>    <int> <int> <int>
>  1     1    11    21
>  2     2    12    22
>  3     3    13    23
>  4     4    14    24
>  5     5    15    25
>  6     6    16    26
>  7     7    17    27
>  8     8    18    28
>  9     9    19    29
> 10    10    20    30
> ```

But then also a warning:

> ```
> Warning message:
> `chr_along()` is soft-deprecated as of rlang 0.2.0.
> This warning is displayed once per session.
> ```

Plot thickens if I don't include `library(rlang)` at all (in a new session), in which case I get no warnings:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
df2 <- tibble(a = 1:10, c = 21:30)

`%J>%` <- function(lhs, rhs){
  inner_join(lhs, rhs)
}

df1 %J>% df2
```

Obviously I don't have to include `library(rlang)` at all in this example, but if I did - this is one weird warning. Where is it coming from and how to avoid it if I did wanted to include `library(rlang)`?

> ```
> sessionInfo()
> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_Israel.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Israel.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Israel.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Israel.1252    
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
> other attached packages:
>  [1] rlang_0.3.0.1   forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.1   dplyr_0.7.6     purrr_0.2.5     readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.8.1     tibble_1.4.2    ggplot2_3.1.0   tidyverse_1.2.1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>  [1] Rcpp_0.12.19     cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.3.0     compiler_3.5.1   plyr_1.8.4       bindr_0.1.1      tools_3.5.1      packrat_0.4.9-3  jsonlite_1.5     lubridate_1.7.4  nlme_3.1-137    
> [12] gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35  pkgconfig_2.0.2  cli_1.0.1        rstudioapi_0.8   haven_1.1.2      bindrcpp_0.2.2   withr_2.1.2      xml2_1.2.0       httr_1.3.1       hms_0.4.2       
> [23] grid_3.5.1       tidyselect_0.2.4 glue_1.3.0       R6_2.2.2         fansi_0.3.0      readxl_1.1.0     modelr_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.2  scales_1.0.0     rvest_0.3.2     
> [34] assertthat_0.2.0 colorspace_1.3-2 utf8_1.1.4       stringi_1.2.4    lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.5.0      crayon_1.3.4
> ```

Comment: @Sotos it worked! Updated rlang and no warnings. Thanks, now I'm contemplating should I delete the question altogether...

Comment: I think there is value to your question. I 'd say leave it on. Let me answer it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I would say that If you load `rlang` as part of the `tidyverse`, (i.e. just load `tidyverse`), then R will use the verse's `rlang` which is automatically updated whithin the verse. If you load `tidyverse` first and then `rlang`, then R will use the last seen one, which is the one you loaded manually. Thus, If you did not update `rlang` manually then It will give the warning. 
The problem should go away If you manually update `rlang`.